# Derivation of Quantum Momentum Operator in Griffiths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, schroedinger-equation, integration

I've been reading through [Griffith's Intro to Quantum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107189632) book and can't understand some of the steps in his derivations. The first one is in his proof of time-independence for the normalization of wave function. Eq 1.25 seems to extract $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ from the terms within the parenthesis.

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx
\tag{1.21}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi|^2 = 
\frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \Psi \right) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \right) \right]
\tag{1.25}
$$

I'm not sure if this makes sense, as "distributing" $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ over the terms would create 4 terms a la product rule right? This is used later when he derives the quantum momentum operator from $\left< x \right>$,

$$
\frac{\partial \left< x \right>}{\partial t} =
\int x \frac{\partial }{\partial t} |\Psi|^2 dx =
\frac{i \hbar}{2m}\int x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi\right) dx
\tag{1.29}
$$

The next step he cites integration-by-parts and product rule, but it looks like he just cancels out the $dx$ and $x$,

$$
\frac{\partial \left< x \right>}{\partial t} =
-\frac{i \hbar}{2m} \int \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi  \right) dx
\tag{1.30}
$$

And then **another** integration-by-parts that I also don't see,

$$
\frac{\partial \left< x \right>}{\partial t} =
-\frac{i \hbar}{m} \int \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} dx
\tag{1.31}
$$

Basically, how did we get 1.25, and what does the outline for the integration-by-parts for 1.30 look like?

Comment: The integration-by-parts for 1.30 & 1.31 are explained in this other post [Integration by parts to derive ⟨⟩/](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192029/integration-by-parts-to-derive-d-langle-x-rangle-dt?rq=1). My question about 1.29 stands though.

Comment: Do you mean he extracts $\partial/\partial x$? For $(1.25)$ he uses the Schrodinger equation to relate the time derivative to a spatial derivative and factors out a $\partial/\partial x$. Have you tried doing the differentiation yourself to see how it comes out?

Comment: @KrisWalker He doesn't *factor* out the $\partial/\partial x$, because OP is right that this should create *four* terms when pushed back through the parentheses. However, if one computes that, one will find that two of the terms cancel each other out.

Comment: @march I'm using the word "factor" very loosely here. I'm aware of the cancellation, which is why I suggested the OP do the differentiation themselves.

Comment: Embarrassingly, you all are very correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration-by-parts for 1.30 & 1.31 are explained in this other post:  [Integration by parts to derive ⟨⟩/](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192029/integration-by-parts-to-derive-d-langle-x-rangle-dt?rq=1).

Equation 1.25 is actually exactly as it seems - the product rule results in two terms that cancel out. Taking the RHS of 1.25,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \right) \right]
\tag{From 1.25}
$$

$$
\frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left[ \left(\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + \Psi^*\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2}\right) -
\left(\frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2}\Psi + \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\right)
\right]
$$

Pretty clearly, the first and last term cancel out, therefore:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left( \Psi^* \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \right) \right] =
\frac{i \hbar}{2m} \left[ \Psi^* \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2} \Psi \right]
$$
Which is Equation 1.25.